# Selecting and modifying DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I select DOM elements in JS? What is the equivalent for jQuery's `$` selection syntax?

For example I have a `<div>` element:

```
<div id="idDiv">Div Element</div>
```

Now I want to apply addClass("ClassName") jQuery function on div.
I can do it with jQuery with the following way:

```
$("#idDiv").addClass("ClassName") or jQuery("#idDiv").addClass("ClassName")
```

How can I do this with vanilla JS?

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("idDiv").className = "ClassName";`

Comment: I want to get jQuery object. I will apply not only addClass function.

Comment: To get DOM element, do this `var element = document.getElementById("idDiv");`

Comment: What makes this a jQuery object, if you aren't using jQuery?

Comment: You can't have a `jQuery` object without using `jQuery`. The object is the function, that's the functional programming paradigm. You can reproduce a lot of the functionality in vanilla JS, but if what you want is to be able to use the jQuery methods, you'll need to use jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `classList` API:

```
// Adding classes
document.getElementById('idDiv').classList.add('foo');
// Toggling classes
document.getElementById('idDiv').classList.toggle('foo');
// Removing classes
document.getElementById('idDiv').classList.remove('bar');
```

Please note that IE9 and below do not support the API, for supporting those browsers you can use a shim, MDN has [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

An experimental solution:

```
function jFoo(selector) {
    return {
        elems: [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector)),
        _handleClass: function (cls, m) {
            var len = this.elems.length,
                cls = cls.trim().split(/\s/),
                clen = cls.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < clen; j++)
                this.elems[i].classList[m](cls[j]);
            }
            return this;
        },
        addClass: function (cls) {
           return this._handleClass(cls, 'add');
        },
        toggleClass: function (cls) {
           return this._handleClass(cls, 'toggle');
        },
        removeClass: function (cls) {
           return this._handleClass(cls, 'remove');
        },
    }
}

jFoo('selector').toggleClass('foo bar')
                .addClass('barz fool')
                .removeClass('foo');
```

Comment: need to warn about IE

Comment: You can't toggle multiple classes. From spec: `If force is not given, "toggles" token, removing it if it's present and adding it if it's not. If force is true, adds token (same as add()). If force is false, removes token (same as remove()).` [DOMTokenList](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#domtokenlist)

Answer (score 1):

You can get element by javascript in following way:

```
    var getelem = document.getElementById("idDiv");

    getelem.setAttribute("class", "active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of adding class using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("idDiv").className += " ClassName";
```